# Is there any way to export a xlsx file with multiple sheets but password protected in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have multiple data frames and want to export them in one xlsx file with multiple sheets. Normally it's possible using `list(sheet1 = df1, sheet2 = df2)`. If I use functions like `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` it works, but I want to write it to have a password. If someone wants to read/open, he/she must have the password.
I have used the function `xlsx::write.xlsx()` but it doesn't support a data frame with multiple sheets. It works perfectly with one single data frame at a time.

Comment: There seems to be a function in the openxlsx package for this: https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/protectWorksheet.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use  openxlsx::protectWorkbook() to protect  a workbook from modifications by the user in the graphical user interface.

Comment: yes, I have tried it, but my point is to restrict it even from viewing. If the user wants to open it, he/she must provide the password for it.